# Membership and Roles for OracleProvider In Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, membership-provider

I am Creating an application in Asp.Net and i am using Oracle 11g as a Backend Tool. But how can i get the schema for Oracle for the inbuilt membership and roles ?

WILL the stored procedure that are declared in SQL SERVER work in oracle ? Is there any tool for that ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am about to do the same...